# Eloquent hasMany returns empty collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have these 2 models

```
class Image extends Model
{

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

}
class Product extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {

        return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

I have these 2 tables linked by product_id

```
This is my product table
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

This is my image table
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->string('sm');
        $table->string('md');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

when I use artisan tinker to check its working  I get an empty result  with this

$a = new App\product $a->images $a::find(1)

but if I run sql from phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM products, images where products.id = images.id AND products.id=1
```

I get results   any help appreciated

```
>>> $a->find(1)
=> App\Product {#3057
     id: 1,
     title: "1",
     price: "1",
     description: "1",
     pic: "1",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
   }
>>> $a->images
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3050
     all: [],
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple

First execute this command. `composer dump-autoload`

Then in your `php artisan tinker;` command you write this

```
$product = \App\Product::find(1);
$product->images;
```

Hope it is help for you.

Comment: If it helps to you please accept the answer for future solver @NijelCollingham